# Method being called twice sometimes

Tags: android, service

I have a service that runs a method in getting the user's location then send's it to a server in a given interval using alarmManager. It's working fine, but sometimes it run twice, seeing double entry in my database, sometimes with difference of 1 second in timestamp, sometimes exact duplicate data, and in LogCat. I've searched for it but I haven't found something similar with my problem.

Here's the code for a my service:

```
  package com.mgtphil.mibackground;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

 import com.mgtphil.mibackground.MyLocation.*;
 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.location.Location;

 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;

import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


// the service that runs in background
public class MIService2 extends Service{

private final Context context = this;

GPSTracker gps;
HttpPost httppost;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();

DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
UserDatabase udb = new UserDatabase(this);

static double latitude;
static double longitude;
String userid;
String timeType;
String lat;
String lon;
Date dt;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v("onCreate","MIService2 Service Created");
}

//MyLocation class
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){
        //Got the location!
        Log.v("MI Service","MI Service gotLocation()");
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        if(!myLocation.gps_enabled && !myLocation.network_enabled){
            Log.v("No Provider Enabled.", "No Provider Enabled. Do nothing.");
        } else {
            if(latitude == 0 && longitude == 0) {
                //TODO                  
            } else {
                sendData();

            }
        }
    }
};
//end

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

Log.v("onStartCommand","MIService2 Service Started");

myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

List<User> user = udb.getAllUser();
for(User ur : user) {
    userid = ur.getUserID();
    timeType = ur.getTimeType();
}
return START_STICKY;
} //end onstartcommand

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}


@Override   
public void onDestroy() {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "MI Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
    udb.close();
    Log.d("onDestroy","Service Stopped");

}

public void sendData() {
    long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
    dt = new Date(dtMili);

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
    {

        try {
            //check db first, and send it's data first
            sendSavedData();

            lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
            lon = String.valueOf(longitude);
            //code to send data to server
            //httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient = new MyHttpClient().getNewHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost(Config.serverAdd); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd","tracking"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid",userid));  // $userid = $_POST['userid'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operationType","track"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeType",timeType));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time",dt.toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",lat));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",lon));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            Log.v("Service Tracker Send Data", "MI Tracker\nUser: " + MI_Tracker.user + "\nTime: " + dt.toString() + "\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude + "\n");

        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Exception","Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }   



    } else {

        Log.v("Sending Failed.","Sending Failed, no Internet.");
        saveData();

    }

} //end sendData

public void saveData() {
    Log.v("Insert: ","Inserting ...");
    db.addTrack(new Track(MI_Tracker.userid, "track", MI_Tracker.timeType, dt.toString(),lat,lon));
}

public void sendSavedData(){
    List<Track> tracks = db.getAllTracks();

    for(Track tr : tracks) {
        boolean del = false;
        try {
            //send data to server

            httpclient = new MyHttpClient().getNewHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost(Config.serverAdd); // make sure the url is correct.

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd","tracking"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid",tr.getUserID()));  // $userid = $_POST['userid'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operationType","track"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeType",tr.getTimeType()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time",tr.getTime()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",tr.getLatitude()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",tr.getLongitude()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            Log.v("Service Send Saved Data: ", "MI Tracker\nUser: " + tr.getUserID()+ "\nTime: " + tr.getTime() + "\nLat: " + tr.getLatitude() + "\nLong: " + tr.getLatitude());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MI Tracker Sending Data\nUser: " + MI_Tracker.user + "\nTime: " + dt.toString() + "\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //delete data after sending it 05-27
            Log.v("Deleting Data","Deleting Data with ID: " + tr.getID());
            del = true;

        } catch(Exception e){
            del = false;
            Log.e("Exception on sendSaveData","Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }   
        //delete the data when there's no error in sending the data
        if(del){
            db.deleteTrack(tr);
        } else {
            Log.v("Service Send Saved Data:","There's an error. Data retained");
        }
    }
  } //end sendSavedData()

} //end class
```

The logcat:

```
05-31 10:02:06.375: D/dalvikvm(2945): GC_EXPLICIT freed 56K, 49% free 3584K/6919K, external 1503K/1811K, paused 48ms
05-31 10:02:22.890: V/MIServiceReceiver onReceive(2945): MIServiceReceiver Started
05-31 10:02:22.898: V/onStartCommand(2945): MIService2 Service Started
05-31 10:02:22.898: V/getLocation(2945): MyLocation getLocation
05-31 10:02:24.734: V/locationListenerNetwork(2945): Network onLocationChanged
05-31 10:02:24.734: V/MI Service(2945): MI Service gotLocation()
05-31 10:02:25.359: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): MI Tracker
05-31 10:02:25.359: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): User: clint
05-31 10:02:25.359: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Time: Fri May 31 10:02:24 GMT+08:00 2013
05-31 10:02:25.359: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Lat: 14.5804712
05-31 10:02:25.359: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Long: 121.0599356
05-31 10:02:25.406: V/locationListenerNetwork(2945): Network onLocationChanged
05-31 10:02:25.406: V/MI Service(2945): MI Service gotLocation()
05-31 10:02:26.289: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): MI Tracker
05-31 10:02:26.289: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): User: clint
05-31 10:02:26.289: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Time: Fri May 31 10:02:25 GMT+08:00 2013
05-31 10:02:26.289: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Lat: 14.5806383
05-31 10:02:26.289: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Long: 121.0591553
05-31 10:05:22.890: V/MIServiceReceiver onReceive(2945): MIServiceReceiver Started
05-31 10:05:22.890: V/onStartCommand(2945): MIService2 Service Started
05-31 10:05:22.890: V/getLocation(2945): MyLocation getLocation
05-31 10:05:24.570: V/locationListenerNetwork(2945): Network onLocationChanged
05-31 10:05:24.570: V/MI Service(2945): MI Service gotLocation()
05-31 10:05:25.234: D/dalvikvm(2945): GC_CONCURRENT freed 514K, 46% free 3803K/6919K, external 1503K/1811K, paused 3ms+3ms
05-31 10:05:25.234: D/Cursor(2945): Database path: trackingDB
05-31 10:05:25.234: D/Cursor(2945): Table name   : null
05-31 10:05:25.234: D/Cursor(2945): Database path: userDB
05-31 10:05:25.234: D/Cursor(2945): Table name   : null
05-31 10:05:25.234: D/Cursor(2945): Database path: trackingDB
05-31 10:05:25.234: D/Cursor(2945): Table name   : null
05-31 10:05:25.257: D/Cursor(2945): Database path: trackingDB
05-31 10:05:25.257: D/Cursor(2945): Table name   : null
05-31 10:05:25.257: D/Cursor(2945): Database path: userDB
05-31 10:05:25.257: D/Cursor(2945): Table name   : null
05-31 10:05:25.390: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): MI Tracker
05-31 10:05:25.390: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): User: clint
05-31 10:05:25.390: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Time: Fri May 31 10:05:24 GMT+08:00 2013
05-31 10:05:25.390: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Lat: 14.580513
05-31 10:05:25.390: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Long: 121.0596886
05-31 10:05:31.875: D/dalvikvm(2945): GC_EXPLICIT freed 214K, 48% free 3604K/6919K, external 1503K/1811K, paused 39ms
05-31 10:08:22.890: V/MIServiceReceiver onReceive(2945): MIServiceReceiver Started
05-31 10:08:22.890: V/onStartCommand(2945): MIService2 Service Started
05-31 10:08:22.890: V/getLocation(2945): MyLocation getLocation
05-31 10:08:24.609: V/locationListenerNetwork(2945): Network onLocationChanged
05-31 10:08:24.609: V/MI Service(2945): MI Service gotLocation()
05-31 10:08:25.531: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): MI Tracker
05-31 10:08:25.531: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): User: clint
05-31 10:08:25.531: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Time: Fri May 31 10:08:24 GMT+08:00 2013
05-31 10:08:25.531: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Lat: 14.5805303
05-31 10:08:25.531: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Long: 121.0598834
05-31 10:08:32.015: D/dalvikvm(2945): GC_EXPLICIT freed 255K, 48% free 3598K/6919K, external 1503K/1811K, paused 40ms
05-31 10:08:32.015: D/Cursor(2945): Database path: trackingDB
05-31 10:08:32.015: D/Cursor(2945): Table name   : null
05-31 10:08:32.015: D/Cursor(2945): Database path: userDB
05-31 10:08:32.015: D/Cursor(2945): Table name   : null
05-31 10:11:22.890: V/MIServiceReceiver onReceive(2945): MIServiceReceiver Started
05-31 10:11:22.898: V/onStartCommand(2945): MIService2 Service Started
05-31 10:11:22.898: V/getLocation(2945): MyLocation getLocation
05-31 10:11:24.625: V/locationListenerNetwork(2945): Network onLocationChanged
05-31 10:11:24.625: V/MI Service(2945): MI Service gotLocation()
05-31 10:11:25.343: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): MI Tracker
05-31 10:11:25.343: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): User: clint
05-31 10:11:25.343: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Time: Fri May 31 10:11:24 GMT+08:00 2013
05-31 10:11:25.343: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Lat: 14.5805254
05-31 10:11:25.343: V/Service Tracker Send Data(2945): Long: 121.0595373
```

my method for alarmManager in my activity: so the whole process is, my activity fires the alarmmanager, with an intent to start a servicereceiver, and the servicereceiver has the intent for the service.

```
public void processTimeOn() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MIServiceReceiver.class);
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval * 1000, pendingIntent);
    Log.v("AlarmManager","Alarm starts in " + interval + " seconds.");
}
```

The log today is a bit different. Im sure the service onStartCommand is called once, the gotLocation() is the one being called twice, sometimes.

Any feedback will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think its more likely that you have issues in setting up your alarm manager, than that you have issues in here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. i will check more on my alarmManager.. please do check my edits, i've included the method of my alarmManager from my activity.

Comment: you should debug your application,it will help you to know how control flow works and how the same method called twice,and before putting your data in database print it using log

Comment: Ok thanks.. i've printed my data in my logs.